# mongodb autodelete in 24 hours does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
 expire_at: {
  type: Date, 
  default: Date.now, 
  index: { expires: '24h' },
},
```

this expires only in 2 minutes it does not wait for 24 hours. Why this behaves like this ?

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: try passing `1d` instead of `24h`